# Meta question about questions: where to post non-code but computer-related questions

Tags: discussion

I have a question I'd like to ask about configuring the ribbon at the top of Visual Studio -- it's a detailed question.  I recall a similar question, and a moderator (or someone) told the question-er that they should've posted the question on another site -- Stack Exchange, maybe.

Where should non-code but still computer-related questions be posted?

Comment: https://superuser.com/

Comment: A question about configuring a programming IDE (such as Visual Studio) is perfectly fine here. This site is for questions related to programming (code) or use of programmer's tools (IDEs, cmopilers, and so forth). You can learn more about this site in the [help]. Also, for future reference you should use one of the Meta sites for questions like this one. The general Meta site is [meta.se], and the one for this site is [meta].